# vba html dropdown without options

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to use VBA to access a website and download some information. In the website are some drop-down boxes that need to be selected before the submit button can be clicked. I figured out one of the boxes, but the other one, which is a date, has no options in the html, even though the drop-down is populated by YYYY MMM going back for several years. I found a section of html that seems to be a function which populates the drop-down. I'm certainly not an expert at html so this is my best guess.

The following is the html for the dropdown:

```
<td valign="top">
  <select name="dateSelect" id="dateSelect" ></select>
</td>
```

And the function which populates the drop-down looks like:

```
var dateSelect = document.getElementById("dateSelect");
     //sel value = YYYYMMM 
     var dateYear = dateSelect.value.substr(0, 4)
     var dateMonth = dateSelect.value.substr(5)
     var months = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
     var years = new Array()
     var d = new Date();
     var startYear = 0;
     if (d.getYear() < 2000)
       startYear = d.getYear() + 1900;
     else
       startYear = d.getYear();
       for (var a = startYear; a >= 2007; a--) {
           years[startYear - a] = a;
       }
     function fillselboxes(theDate) {
       var d = new Date();
       theDate = new Date(theDate);
       var dateSelect = document.getElementById("dateSelect");
       for (var a = 0; a < years.length; a++) {
          for (var b = months.length - 1; b >= 0; b--) {
             addOption(dateSelect, years[a] + " " + months[b], years[a] + "_" + (b + 1));
          }
       }
       dateSelect.value = years[startYear - theDate.getFullYear()] + "_" + (theDate.getMonth() + 1);
   }
```

In my macro, I want to select last month from the dropdown. As a noob, the only thing I could think of to try was:

```
Dim ie as InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "redacted"

Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

ie.getElementById("dateselect").Value = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "YYYY MMM")
```

When I try that, it gives me a Runtime Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: You're missing semicolons on some of your lines. They aren't strictly required, but they can help avoid errors down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to supply a bit more of your code other than the one line, what is IE, is it a IE document, the browser?  Going to guess a few parts but the answer is below

```
'ie - assuming this is the browser
Dim hElem
hElem = ie.Document.getElementsByName("dateselect")
hElem.selectedIndex = hElem.Length - 1
```

Comment: Yes ie is the browser. I edited my question to show more code. The code that finally worked is: `Set hElem = ie.document.getelementbyid("dateselect")`